# Check if command line arguments are on a new line

Tags: java

How can you check if command line arguments are on a new line?

Example of arguments:

```
3
1 2 4
3 3
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

  for (int index = 0; index < args.length; ++index)
  {
      //if arg is on new line
      System.out.println("args[" + index + "]: " + args[index]);
      }


  }
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to pass command line arguments in different lines, why don't you use delimiter instead of newline

Answer (score 1):

You typically can't without using a `for each` or `while` loop and reading lines using `readLine()` on the `Console` class until you hit some sentinel value.

Hitting [Enter] on the keyboard would run the program, so you can't add a newline as input, unless you use the mechanism I described above.